# Why does this function not invoke the move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am following the video lectures of Stephan T. Lavavej, namely this one on move semantics: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-9-of-n

In the lecture, Stephan gives an example class named remote_integer and defines a global function as follows:

```
remote_integer square(const remote_integer &r) {
  const int i = r.get();
  return remote_integer(i*i);
}
```

The class remote_integer contains a move constructor, however, I've noticed that when the function square is called when trying to initialize a new object, the move constructor does not work as intended.

Here's the code:

```
  remote_integer a(8);
  // Expect move constructor to be called
  remote_integer b = square(a);
```

When I change the function definition of square as follows, the move constructor does work as intended.

```
remote_integer square(const remote_integer &r) {
  const int i = r.get();
  remote_integer local(i*i);
  return local;
}
```

Why is the move constructor called in the second case, but not in the first case? Obviously in the modified square function, the remote_integer is local the the scope of the function, so it's pretty clear that the move constructor is called when the variable local is returned. But why does this not occur when I return an anonymous object as in the first function definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First one**: RVO - return value optimization, construct in place in the call site

**Second one**: Copy elision - elide copies / moves and construct in place

**Third one**: Inhibits RVO, moves the object out of the function

Comment: Good Description +1 for the answer

Comment: You can actually optimize out moves/copies even if it *does* change semantics.  Copy elision is one of the very few exceptions (and the only exception i can think of) to the as-if rule.  Even if the copy/move constructor has side effects, the compiler isn't required to call it.

Comment: BTW, RVO is a form of copy elision.

Comment: Note that `NRVO` may apply in third case.